# How to make a full justify alignment in LaTeX article?

Tags: latex

I'm beginner in LaTeX. I tried few examples, but I can't do a full justify alignment. Maybe this question isn't very annoying and you could help.

There is my code example:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
    \title{text text text text text text text text text text text text}
    \author {text text text text}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    \center{\textit{ text text text text text text}}
    \center{\textit{ text text text text text text}}\\
    \small\textbf{Abstract.}
    An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript or typescript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given academic paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{\large Preface}
     Academic literature uses the abstract to succinctly communicate complex research. An abstract may act as a stand-alone entity instead of a full paper. As such, an abstract is used by many organizations as the basis for selecting research that is proposed for presentation in the form of a poster, platform/oral presentation or workshop presentation at an academic conference. Most literature database search engines index only abstracts rather than providing the entire text of the paper. Full texts of scientific papers must often be purchased because of copyright and/or publisher fees and therefore the abstract is a significant selling point for the reprint or electronic form of the full text.
    \section*{\large Some theory}
    An abstract allows one to sift through copious amounts of papers for ones in which the researcher can have more confidence that they will be relevant to his or her research. Once papers are chosen based on the abstract, they must be read carefully to be evaluated for relevance. It is commonly surmised that one must not base reference citations on the abstract alone, but the entire merits of a paper.\\
    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
\center{\textit{ text text text text text text}}
```

is not the right way to do it. This \center takes effect for the eintire document. (This would also be the case with \raggedright or \raggedleft) There is no way to get back to justified alignment once you set the global alignment to something else (center raggedright or raggedleft)

You should put the brackets before the \center tag ... that is

```
{\center\textit{ text text text text text text}}
```

(this would however not put the text you want to center in the middle of the page but only into a box in the left part though the text will be centered in there). The clean way to do what you probably want to do is to use the center environment (\begin{center} and \end{center})

```
\begin{center}\textit{ text text text text text text}\end{center}
```